# Javascript map variable

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm looking to implement a c++ map variable type in JavaScript but can not seeing anything on the internet. When I used SFML I created a std::map of type String and SFML::Texture so I could store a texture inside of the map and get the texture value by using the key, how would I implement this into JavaScript?

The reason I want to do this is I want to load all image assets at the start of my HTML5 game, and then I can call on the image map and get the image reference using the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way in JavaScript is just an object:

```
var map = {};
map["any key you like"] = any_value_you_like;

// Also:
map.any_name_you_like_that_fits_identifer_name_rules = any_value_you_like;
```

The keys are always strings (for now, ES6 will add symbol/name keys), the values are any JavaScript value. When you use dot notation (`obj.foo`), the property name is a literal (and subject to JavaScript's rules for *IdentifierName*); when you use brackets notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`), the property name can be just about anything (and can be the result of any expression, such as a variable lookup).

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xobeb/1)

```
var map = {};
map["a"] = "alpha";
map["b"] = "beta";
map["c"] = "gamma";

["a", "b", "c"].forEach(function(key) {
  display("map['" + key + "'] = " + map[key]);
});
```

Output:

```
map['a'] = alpha
map['b'] = beta
map['c'] = gamma
```

---

[dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) raises an interesting point: When you create an object via `{}`, it inherits properties from `Object.prototype`, but as of ES5 you can use `Object.create(null)`, which doesn't:

```
var map = Object.create(null);
map["any key you like"] = any_value_you_like;

// Also:
map.any_name_you_like_that_fits_identifer_name_rules = any_value_you_like;
```

That way, if you happen to have the potential for keys with names like `toString` or `valueOf` (which are on `Object.prototype`), you won't get false positives when looking them up on an object where you haven't set them explicitly.

Comment: you might consider using "Object.create(null)" instead of "{}" becasue the result won't be pre-populated with properties like toString(), hasOwnProperty(), \_\_proto\_\_, constructor, etc...

Comment: @dandavis: Since those are non-enumerable and you can shadow them with own properties, there's little need. But yes it's an option, and an interesting one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: well, the big advantage to Object.create(null) is that it allows for faster property access everywhere in the app when fetching because you can just grab map[anything] and not have to worry about calling hasOwnProperty.call(map, anything), or getting stuff out you didn't put in. that makes it more like a C++ map. good update TJ.

Comment: @dandavis: I usually don't bother with `hasOwnProperty` anyway (and usually prefix property names), but as I said, very interesting option (not least because it does away with the prefixing).

Comment: @dandavis: These make interesting reading: [Creating is markedly slower](http://jsperf.com/literal-vs-object-create-null) with `Object.create` vs. `{}`, but who cares, you don't do that often; [raw access is about the same](http://jsperf.com/prop-access-with-and-without-prototype) but has (as we've said) the potential for false positives; [prefixed access is much, much slower](http://jsperf.com/prop-access-with-and-without-prototype/2). On the whole, `Object.create(null)` looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `Map` data structure. It was introduced in JavaScript via ES6 and allows to create collections of key-value pairs. Unlike objects, a map object can hold both objects and primitives as keys and values. Here is example:

```
const items = new Map();

// add items
items.set('', 'Dog');
items.set('', 'Eagle');
items.set('', 'Train');
items.set(45, 'Number');
items.set(true, 'Boolean');

// iterate over map
for (const [key, value] of items) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Output:

```
: Dog
: Eagle
: Train
45: Number
true: Boolean
```

[More examples](https://attacomsian.com/blog/maps-javascript)